# Why are Angular modules that get exported to npm packages require (and enforce) a different structure?

Tags: angular

I wrote a simple library of presentational components, which I wrapped up and exported using an Angular module.

When the module is imported from a seperate folder in the `src` directory (eg `/src/mycomponents/mycomponents.module`), all is well, but as soon as I publish/import it to/from npm, the compiler throws errors about module structure.

The way around this seems to be using tools like `ng-packagr`. This feels strange and unnecessary though, why does the Angular team enforce external modules to conform to a particular structure?

Feels intuitive that if my library can be compiled by the host project's compiler when it's located within that project, the host compiler should be able to build it when that same source is referenced from an external source

Comment: NPM is a JavaScript package manager, while Angular modules are TypeScript.  Programs like `ng-packagr` transpile the code first.

Comment: Oh I see. Does that mean It checks to see if the content coming from NPM is javascript, failing if it is not? I just assumed you could store anything arbitrarily without issue